# While using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I believe part of the below code is incorrect. Please tell me how I can fix this to make the model run. Use the image for full code details.

```
*model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

*model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

[image]

Comment: What are the shapes of your `x_train` and y`train`, respectively?

Comment: shape_y
shape_x = x_train.shape
print(shape_x)
​
shape_y = y_train.shape
print(shape_y)
(15000, 250)
(15000, 250)

Comment: the shapes look wrong for binary_crossentropy. For the loss to work, shape_y needs to be (batch_size, 1), which is (15000, 1) in your case. Each length-1 vector indicates the true/false (1/0) value for the particular input example.

Comment: Should I use a different loss function?